# Find a lower bound on $a^2(\boldsymbol{x}^\textrm{T}\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{y})^2-(\boldsymbol{x}^\textrm{T}\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x})^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, upper-lower-bounds

I wonder if there is a good to find the lower bound of the following term:
\begin{equation}
\min_{\boldsymbol{x}}\,a^2(\boldsymbol{x}^\textrm{T}\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{y})^2-(\boldsymbol{x}^\textrm{T}\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x})^2
\end{equation}
where $a>0$ is some constant; $\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ have unit norm; and $\boldsymbol{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a symmetric matrix. $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{y}$ are known. It can also be written as:
\begin{equation}
\min_{\boldsymbol{x}}\,(a\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{x})^\textrm{T}\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}\boldsymbol{x}^\textrm{T}\boldsymbol{A}(a\boldsymbol{y}+\boldsymbol{x})
\end{equation}
or 
\begin{equation}
\min_{\boldsymbol{x}}\,\boldsymbol{x}^\textrm{T}\boldsymbol{A}(a^2\boldsymbol{y}\boldsymbol{y}^\textrm{T}-\boldsymbol{x}\boldsymbol{x}^\textrm{T})\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}
\end{equation}
This is related to an earlier trivial question I asked, any help is greatly appreciated, thanks so much!

**Edit**: In other words, is there an $a$ that could make the above term greater than $0$?

Comment: How tight of a lower bound are you looking for? A  trivial one is $-\lambda^2$, where $\lambda$ is the largest-magnitude eigenvalue of $A$. I'd be surprised if the problem itself has a closed-form solution; one starting point is that you may as well assume $A$ is diagonal, by switching to its eigenvector basis.

Comment: @user7530 Thanks! Preferably the lower bound would be something with respect to $a$

Comment: Note that the lower bound will not always depend on $a$; for example if $y$ is an eigenvector other than the one corresponding to the largest-magnitude eigenvalue, the minimum will be $-\lambda^2$ regardless of $a$.

Comment: @user7530 Thanks, I see. If I want to make the above term greater than $0$, what would be a good choice of $a$? This is why I want the lower bound depend on $a$.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

For any $y$, there is an $(n-1)$-dimensional space of vectors $x$ with $x^TAy =0$ (the orthogonal complement of $Ay$). For any of these vectors and for any $a$,
$$a^2 (x^TAy)^2 - (x^TAx)^2 = -(x^TAx)^2 <= 0,$$
with equality only if $x$ is in the kernel of $A$. Therefore the only time that the minimum is guaranteed to be nonnegative is if $A=0$, or $A$ has rank one with $y$ in the column space of $A$ (in which case any $a\geq 1$ will do).